# Process.Start() working under Win7 and Win8 but not Windows 2012 R2

Tags: c#, windows, process, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

My program, run via a Windows Service was able to successfully run the following code under Win7 and Win8.

```
Log("About to run the file...");
try
{
    Process.Start(filePath, args);
    Log("File Triggered!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log("Error.");
}
```

Although the `UI` of the program located at `filePath` was never shown, but the program did its job completely in the background.

When I try the exact same program on a Windows 2012 R2 environment, I notice that after receiving the first log message above in my log file ("About to run the file...") nothing else is logged and `Process.Start()` does not work either. This is confusing because the exact same program worked in other operating systems.

So if `Process.Start()` is not called successfully, who do I not receive the "Error" message in my log and if `Process.Start()` is run, why do I not get the "File Triggered!" message?

**Update:** 
Following the comments, I ran Process Monitor and this is the log generated for the target .exe file at the exact minute that it was supposed to run. Please take a look and see you find anything suspicious:

[Link to log spreadsheet on Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xCcuL0-ZfmRBizLCiuwpl8OJzaVntNJ3lcA43XH2-ww/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2012 blocks all the files copied from other places. So I unblocked all the program files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you unblocked the files?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because Windows Server 2012 does not by default allow processes to run interactively.

[See here for details.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can override this behaviour by setting a registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
NoInteractiveServices
```

Set the value to "0".

Comment: But you were right. The value of the key was 1 and it did not allow interactive processes and I made some progress with that.

Answer (score 1):

1. What's in process viewer -- do you see your process to start?
2. What's in Windows Event Log?
3. Win2012 is probably more strict regarding security and your application (executed from service, thus quite specific user). You can try using FileMon/ProcessMonitor from SysInternals to check which call it is failing at or stuck at.

And a generic advice: starting UI from service in Windows is not the best practice. Services are created to do some background work and not to have user interaction. If you need UI for your service, better create UI that user start himself, of create a small app that will sit in tray and wait for an event from service and then start UI in user so called "window station".

Comment: The thing is the program I have written to be run by the service works in both modes. So if the user is logged, s/he will be able to see the window, otherwise the program will start and be closed by itself. And this has been a working scenario for the other instances of my program I have installed on other machines. I'm going to take a look at Windows Event Log as you say. Hope I can find something that explains why the program is not run.

Comment: What if there are two users -- one using phisical termina (keyboard, monitor) and the other one is coming via terminal services client? What if your program to run in headless windows install (afair).
I would strongly suggest, if there is a real need to run UI program from a service, to check, how to run UI within specific [Window Station](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I check now and find nothing related to my program in the event log. no crash reports. what makes this very strange for me is that, looking at the code i have written above. the service is working because the first log message is always written ("About to run the file..."). What I don't understand is, even if my `Process.Start()` is not working properly or even if it it silently just passes by, why do I not receive any other log. Neither ("File Triggered!") nor ("Error.")

Comment: I will give Process Monitor a try now.

Comment: I installed Process Monitor and logged Everything regarding that target .exe file that was supposed to be run by my service at its designated time. The name of the exe file is `FileCampaignRunner`. Here is where I have uploaded it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xCcuL0-ZfmRBizLCiuwpl8OJzaVntNJ3lcA43XH2-ww/edit#gid=0 please take a look and see if you find anything suspicious. I see some SHARING VIOLATION errors. Do you Think that's what is blocking the file?

Comment: I'd suggest the following reading:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/b/voy/archive/2007/02/23/services-isolation-in-session-0-of-windows-vista-and-longhorn-server.aspx

Once again, services are built to work without user interaction. Windows 2012 (probably) brings even more strict limitations and I'd strongly suggest making user-space independant application. They (service and UI app) can share the same code at the same time

Comment: I have read this link and have set the value to 0. @Matthew Watson's comment suggests the same thing. But still not working.